# Chrome is reporting a wrong event.timeStamp value (6 digit or negative values)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
$("p").on( "mousemove", function(event) {
   $("p").text(event.timeStamp);
});
```

It returns a 9 digit positive value in both Firefox and Edge but in Chrome only a six digit decimal number. My chrome version is 43. What is wrong here?

**EDIT** : I updated my Chrome version but I still get either negative time values or a six digit number. My Chrome version is 48 now. I am using Window 10 64 bit if that matters.

**EDIT 2** : When I reload my page, for a brief period of time the value is positive. After that it becomes negative. The negative value decreases with time and finally, it becomes positive and keeps increasing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/j7vg30q6/2/ in 48 it looks fine

Comment: It returns a number with more digits than that (try 13 instead of 9). Anyway, if the reported lengths are (or were) correct, it sounds to be milliseconds vs seconds (3 less digits) - although negative values..

Comment: I see the 'correct' values in Chrome 47, Windows 7 64bit. Does using `new Date().valueOf()` return a reasonable result?

Comment: @user2864740 I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I also get negative time in your fiddle.

Comment: What is your system time?

Comment: At this time is it 10:56:08 1 February, 2016.

Answer (score 2):

In chrome (version 48/49... m) the event.timeStamp return a float value, something like 18000.123..

I have simply stopped using event.timeStamp and instead I have put Date.now(), which is not as precise but avoid this issue.

[**reference**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=578243&q=label%3AM-49&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like `event.timeStamp` is now milliseconds since page load rather than milliseconds since January 1st 1970 00:00:00 (as defined in the specification).

I check this by comparing `event.timeStamp` to `performance.now()` which are the same.